# Read an SQL table into variables on a website

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I've developed a stored procedure on the SQL server that builds a nice, sorted, table for me.

Some of the columns in the rows of the table are:

```
    Mem_ID,   Mem_Name,   LI,   RA, WI_Desc, WI_Alla,    L_Award   ,          Chg
    12        Frank       90    76   Dagger   11287   2014-02-03 00:00  2014-01-31 00:00
    35        John        -2    14   Dagger   11287   2008-06-05 00:00  2014-04-27 00:00
    15        Gus         15    36   E-Peen   13145   2015-02-04 00:00  2014-01-20 00:00
```

... etc (I hope that stays formatted like I typed it in)

Problem:
I now want to create a web page that will read in this table a row at a time, assigning each column to a variable that will let me then work with the various bits of data to construct an html style table such as:

```
<table cellpadding="5" bgcolor="Slate"> <tr bgcolor="blue"> <td align="Center" colspan="7"> <b> <font size="10" color="White"> Wish List </font> </b> </tr><tr bgcolor="Black"> <td align="Left"> <font size="10" color="White">  <td align="Left"> <font size="10" color="White"> Name <td align="Left"> <font size="10" color="White"> Loot Index <td align="Left"> <font size="10" color="White"> RA <td align="Left"> <font size="10" color="White"> Change Date <td align="Left"> <font size="10" color="White"> Eligible? <tr bgcolor="Lime"> <td align="LEFT" colspan="7"> <b> <font size="10" color="blue"><a href="http://everquest.allakhazam.com/db/item.html?item=11287" target="_blank">Dagger</a></td></tr>
```

and then list out the Members that have that particular item, in this case it would be Frank and John's rows, then create another spanning row for the E-Peen item, and list out the person below that (in this case it's Gus).  Now the Eligible condition requires evaluation of some of the data that is in the original table... The LI has to be greater than negative 1, The Chg has to have been at least 8 days ago, The RA has to be greater than 50, The L_Award has to have been at least 45 days ago.  (I can do this part of the coding, IF someone can explain / list how to read the rows of the table into variables that I can then work with before constructing the

```
<tr> ...
```

for that row.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use deprecated HTML. Use CSS to style your table instead.

Comment: And be sure to use PDO functions, not MySql, which are depreciated.  Take a look at the pages:    

http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/display-data-array-mysql-html-table_t    
 and 
 http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/pdo-select-query-fetch   and   

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338   

and   http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: You need to access your databse using PDO (as @Mawg pointed out). And then loop through the results. The ouput depends if you are using plain PHP (just echo the rows) or if you are using some templating engine. I suggest to have a look at the tutorials already mentioned and then opening specific questions, as this one is way to broad.

Comment: Mawg - Thank you for the links to the tutorials, and the information, it gave me a good starter for where to go since I didn't have a clue.